# css transition not applied for backgroundimage property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am not able to apply the transition property on hover for changing the gradient.  I have attached the code for reference. I am not sure, where I am going wrong.

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

#grad1:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Comment: `background-color` and `background-image` are two separate properties.

Comment: short answer: you cannot apply transtion to gradient ... long answer: check the duplicate for workarounds